# Beste way to change IP address for many domains at once

Tags: dns, ip, domain

I have to move several servers to another location, which means that the IP address is going to change. Three of these servers - or better IP addresses - have several thousand domains linked to them via A-records. Some of these domains have subdomains with CNAME records, but it's mostly A-records.

Currently I think about pointing all domains via CNAME to a handful of master-domains (<10) with a short TTL (5 minutes or so). Then it will take several minutes to change the IP address for these "master-domains". I guess all domains that are linked via CNAME will be updated at the same time as the master domain is updated, but maybe this is not how it works. Are there downsides to using CNAMES for so many domains? Will that affect Google ranking, or have other side-effects?

Will a short TTL have downsides? This has to be set at least one day before the move, as the current TTL is one day.

In the past I've done this for a small number of domains by creating a www2 subdomain, which pointed to the new IP address. Then I migrated the website, changed the DNS for the domain and for www, disabled the old site and created a 301 redirect from www (old server) to www2 (new server). The new server served the same site for www and www2, so would pick up the normal site as soon as the DNS was updated worldwide. Then I would change the www2 to a 301 redirect to www (now on the new server) and after a while I would serve an error page for www2 with explanation. This was for a service that didn't bother with Google ranking. In this case I don't think this is a good alternative, but maybe you disagree.

I want to keep control and an option to go back if the migration is problematic. The setup is doable but complex, and I know we need an option to go back in case we cannot get it working. I suppose changing the IP address back to the old one should to it.

What do you think is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Just quickly are you talking about internal or external DNS TTL's remembering that short TTL's internally will still take up to 24 hours to propagate in the outside world...

Comment: External DNS. All domains are hosted with an external provider.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment but more advice than an answer per say.

Its hard to say 100% however my thoughts and theories on this are that:

1. Any mass change for example replace this IP with this IP the provider should be able to do for you instantly.
2. The TTL will most likely be for their own DNS Servers which is very limiting as it will not populate to the whole world DNS servers any faster it will just cause more internal traffic every five minutes for the provider. The population for all DNS will still be up to 24 hours.
3. Possibly your best move would be to point them all towards a DynDns address (unsure how much you know about this so I won't explain unless you ask me too) this way you can change on the fly as and when you need too, and reverse back to the old IP almost instantly if it all goes sour!

Edit: Also I do not believe that TTL has any negative affect on Google rankings however not 100% sure on this.

Edit 2: Sorry another thought, if you are going to take the DynDns route and want to make this more seamless then I would get the DynDns setup to the current IP, change your A records with provider to the DynDns and then use the DynDns to swap the IP over when your are ready to go! This was you can swap test instantly and swap back if needed.

Comment: Thanks! Dyndns is an interesting option to consider. About TTL you say that it will take 24 hours anyway?! That's good to know! I thought the TTL value really made a difference.